# Getting started with Jetson Tegra K1

Tags: linux

After working for a long time on my Arduino Due, I needed a better and more powerful prototyping platform for my future projects. For which, I have placed an order for NVIDIA Jetson Tegra K1 board which runs on linux and supports CUDA based development. Being a newbie to Linux, I have no idea where to start from and what to do for getting started with code execution on the Jetson board. Please suggest the initial steps required and from where can I get familiar to Linux environment...

Thank you

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? Are you asking about getting familiar with Linux in general? Are you asking about getting familiar with the terminal? Are you asking about what editors and compilers are available? Are you asking about coding for and programming of Jetson Tegra K1?

Comment: It would be a good idea to say what you know already. For example, are you able to write a hello world C program in Linux, compile and run it?

Comment: Aah ... Basically, I know quite a lot about C/C++ programming but I am totally new to the Linux environment and its terminal commands, hence, new to Jetson's environment. It would be great if I start form the basics ... I guess.

Comment: How about [this tutorial](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/) that introduces the terminal, basic commands (`bash`), a nice editor (`vi`), manual pages etc? If you search on google, you can find many more of these tutorials.

Comment: This is a question about getting started in a *nix OS, and would be better asked on other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into ROS. It's a communications protocol that allows for easy communication between two pieces of code. It works with python and cpp and handles all the  building and compiling. There are a ton of ROS libraries, called packages, which the community has put together and maintains.

It looks like ros indigo has been successfully built in using the jetson tk1.

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

Here are some ros tutorials that cover all of the basics.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials